# echo mix of php and html - synatx

Tags: php

i'm trying to get a thumbnail to display if it exists within a div class, but it's outputting code in unexpected ways (like the permalink is outside of the href)

what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
 if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
   $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
   echo '<div class="thumbnail"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . $image[0] . '</a></div>';
 } else {
   echo '';
 }
?>
```

results in

```
 http://www.permalink.com/<div class="thumbnail"><a href="">http://www.mysite.com/wp_myblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/fretless-thumbnail1.jpg</a></div>
```

and no, i didn't leave out any carrots, brackets, quotes or any other code. this is copy and past exactly how it is outputing

**EDIT : THE FIX**

i had to add some extra html since the fix only spit out the jpg url sans `img` tags. plus, it wasn't displaying the correct image - it was showing the original jpg instead of the thumbnail version

```
<?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
        echo '<div class="thumbnail"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . '<img src="' . $image[0] . '"></a></div>';
    }
?>
```

YAY!

Comment: Does the server know it's a PHP document?

Comment: edited to include the output. and yes, this is a valid php document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`the_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) function includes an `echo` statement already.

Change it to [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), and it should work correctly:

```
<?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        echo '<div class="thumbnail"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $image[0] . '</a></div>';
    }
?>
```

You don't really need the `else` bit, either. It's probably redundant.

In fact, for a slightly more neater alternative, this would probably work (amended from my own code; just added the link):

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <div class="hover_img">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: AH! i knew it was going to be something simple like that. thank you! but this causes another problem you may be able to answer. it's not outputting the correct image. even though i have the featured image set to thumbnail, the page is displaying the full size image. is this another alternate call issue?

Comment: I've added a cleaner solution too @kristinachilds :)

Comment: that's how i would normally do it, but the parent html is also continent on there being a featured image assigned tot he post. otherwise you end up with empty boxes on each archive page (css has a border around the image)